# D3.js: How to pan by both axis, but zoom only by one?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It's not a duplicate question of [D3: Is it possible to zoom+pan one axis and only pan the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215202), 
Current d3  version doesn't have any more the function zoom().x()

I am trying to make panning by x and y, but zoom only by y.
And totally don't know how to implement it. Currently I have this version, that pans in both axis, and it fine, but zooms also by both axis, and I need to limit/restrict x zooming.

Appreciate any help.

```
 this.zoom = d3.zoom()
                  .scaleExtent([0.01, 9000])
                  .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [100, 100]])
                  .extent([[0,0], [500, 500]])
                  .on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this))
 zoomed() {
  this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, 1000])
                    .range([0, 100]);
  this.xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([-20, 2000])
                    .range([0, 100]);
  this.yScale.domain(zoomTransform.rescaleY(this.yScale).domain());
  this.xScale.domain(zoomTransform.rescaleX(this.xScale).domain());

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3: Is it possible to zoom+pan one axis and only pan the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215202/d3-is-it-possible-to-zoompan-one-axis-and-only-pan-the-other)

Comment: @i It's not duplicate,  that question was about d3 v3, that had zoom().x() function,  v4 doesn't have it

Comment: FYI - the current version of d3 is v5. :)

Comment: @ialarmedalien does it contain a decision for my problem?

Comment: See [github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/48](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/48) -- this is basically a big gap in d3-zoom's capabilities. There are a few ways around the issue, but this drop-in replacement for d3-zoom seems reasonable: https://github.com/wiremind/d3-xyzoom