# D3.js: Get pan translation without zoom without d3.drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to Pan+Zoom along the X axis but ONLY pan along the Y axis, and I'd like to do this WITHOUT using d3.drag as in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35445448/297824).

The D3 Zoom behavior returns a translation, which is exactly what I want EXCEPT that the Y component is also modified by zooming (which makes sense when you want to pan+zoom in the ordinary way). Would there be a way of 'correcting' the Y component with the scale? I tried y/k but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I believe you are trying to manipulate a graph/chart - is this correct? Or are you trying to manipulate something else? (there may be slightly different considerations for different options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that 1) this is a known deficiency in D3's Zoom lib, and 2) someone made a [replacement lib](https://github.com/wiremind/d3-xyzoom) that does EXACTLY what I wanted:

```
let zoomBehavior = d3.xyzoom()
  .scaleRatio([1,0])                // <- controls x & y scales independently
  .extent([[0, 0], [this.w, this.h]])
  .on('zoom', this.zoomHandler.bind(this));
```